# Use a for loop to set the titles for buttons

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, button, indexpath

I want to use a for loop to set the titles for the button. What I am currently doing is not working. I thought using indexPath.row was working but it does not. The code is not compelling either. I would think there is a simple solution to implement the array.

```
         var line = UIButton()
var pen = UIButton()
var graph = UIButton()
var save = UIButton()
var nxt = UIButton()

        let btnTitles = ["line","pen","graph","save","next"]
    var increase = 0.1
    for b in [line, pen, graph,save,nxt] {

        b.setTitle(btnTitles(IndexPath.row), for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: What are the things that you call buttons?  `IBOutlet` `UIButton` objects?  `UIButton` objects that you create programmatically?  I don't see it in your code.

Comment: I added some stuff

Comment: let buttons: [UIButtons] = [line, pen, graph, save, nxt]
let btnTitles = ["line","pen","graph","save","next"]
for i in 0..<buttons.count {
 let button = buttons[i]
 let title = btnTitles[i]
 button.setTitle(title, forState:.Normal)
}

Comment: can you write that as a answer I am having trouble copying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let line = UIButton()
let pen = UIButton()
let graph = UIButton()
let save = UIButton()
let nxt = UIButton()

let buttons: [UIButton] = [line, pen, graph, save, nxt]
let btnTitles = ["line", "pen", "graph", "save", "next"]
for i in 0..<buttons.count {
    let button = buttons[i]
    let title = btnTitles[i]
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
}

// probing code //
buttons.forEach {
    if let title = $0.titleLabel?.text {
       print(title)
    }
}
```

It prints as follows.

line
pen
graph
save
next